# Understanding Python Code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy!

I tried to understand the Python Code from the locator package and have problems to find the answer what are the parameter "map_frame" and the "odom_frame"?
Where gets rospy this parameters?

self.map_frame = rospy.get_param('map_frame', 'map')
self.odom_frame = rospy.get_param('odom_frame', 'odom')

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50734/understanding-python-code/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please tag your questions.

It's getting these parameters from the ROS parameter server. Have a look at the [ros tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1